# ASP.NET Pros and Cons of two different ways of displaying data on website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I know of two ways to display data on a website.

The first is by using adding a DB connection to the Server Explorer and then dragging the table you want to display on the webpage. Visual Studio does all the backend stuff for you.

The second is where you just choose the control you want to use and you hook it up manually through code for it to display the data you want. You do not have to connect to the DB in server explorer. Something like this in code behind:

```
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RawToSummary", sqlConnection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@SDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = MySDate;
        command.Parameters.Add("@EDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = MyEDate;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();

private DataTable FillData(string connString, SqlCommand cmd)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    DataTable dt = null;
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tableName");
        dt = ds.Tables["tableName"];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WriteLog("Error: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the second method called? I am trying to learn more about it but need a Google search term for it.

2) What are the pros and cons of each method?

I am using the following: Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: You can add keyword 'programmatically' to your current search terms to get results of how to do stuff by code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Explorer/Database Explorer** is the server management console for Visual Studio. Use this window to open data connections and to log on to servers and explore their system services.

With Server Explorer/Database Explorer we can view and retrieve information from all of the databases connected to. like:

- List database tables, views, stored procedures, and functions
- Expand individual tables to list their columns and triggers
- Right-click a table to perform actions, such as showing the table's
  data or viewing the table's definition, from its shortcut menu.

**Programmatic approach**
Second approach is the programmatic approach to perform the DM (data manipulation) and DD (data definition) functions.

Server Explorer/Database Explorer goes through the same course (connecting with database, query tables etc.) but in the background while in programmatic approach we write commands (queries/stored procedures) for the same.

I hope this gives an idea.

Comment: Do you by any chance know where I can learn the programmatic approach? 

I still don't understand why one would use the programmatic approach instead of just letting Visual Studio do all the work.

Comment: You need to access queries/stored procedures programmatically , DB Explorer will not do 100% jobs you need. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038536/Day-Database-Connectivity-ASP-NET-Csharp-with-SQL